# kibana-Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes.missing authentication credentials for REST request

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, kibana

Im trying to Install kibana 8.1.1 on windows10 the thing is when it starts installions it stops on an error like that
`[2022-04-16T01:16:59.744+00:00][ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version  information from Elasticsearch nodes. security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: missing  authentication credentials for REST request [/_nodes?  filter_path=nodes..version%2Cnodes..http.publish_address%2Cnodes.*.ip]`

i tried so many solutions like, I did change the elastisearch.yml file
`xpack.security.enabled: false`

but it is still doesn't work an i did it on kibana.yml too still same
i did add this folowing lines too

```
`xpack.security.enabled: true  
xpack.monitoring.enabled: true  
xpack.monitoring.ui.enabled: true  
xpack.security.encryptionKey: "XXX"`
```

still nothing.

i removed the # on kibana.yml too before the
`elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]`

and stiiiill noothing
here is
kibana.yml:
`server.port: 5601   server.host: "localhost"   server.name: "your-hostname"   elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]`

elasticsearch.yml:

```
`cluster.name: my-application  
network.host: 192.168.0.1  
node.name: node-1  
discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]  
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]`
```

im soo sorry about my english its not my first langage and for not knowing what to do its for studies project and im still a beginner
google is not helping too
thank u for helping me

Answer (score 22):

A more detailed steps as below,

Step 1 is required only when you made some changes to both yml files.

1. Comment everything in elastic and Kibana yml and save
2. Start Elasticsearch
3. Open another command prompt from the directory elasticsearch-8.0.0\bin and run the below command.

Note: We are resetting password for user "kibana_system" not "elastic".

```sh
.\elasticsearch-reset-password.bat -u kibana_system --auto
```

This command will give you password for user "kibana_system". Copy and store the password somewhere.

4. Edit kibana yml file in kibana-8.0.0\bin directory by setting below values.

```yaml
elasticsearch.username: "kibana_system"
elasticsearch.password: "the kibana_system password generated above, not the elastic password"
```

Then save the yml file.

5. start kibana, wait till you see everything is fine and no error.
6. open http://localhost:5601/app/home#/ in the browser.
   Enter username as "elastic"
   Enter the password as "the elastic password, not kibana password"

Comment: I have done one more step that is required me to solve the error is :uncomment the `elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: *none*` in `kibana.yaml` and set the value to **none**. Then only i can see the kibana dashboard screen. (Note as per doc: **none** is not advisable for prod.

Answer (score 1):

```
elasticsearch.username: "kibana_system"
elasticsearch.password: <my-kibana_system-password>
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message `Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. write EPROTO 140439658473408:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number` indicates an SSL-related issue when trying to communicate with Elasticsearch nodes.

To resolve this error, make sure that the Elasticsearch host you are connecting to is serving requests over HTTPS instead of HTTP. May be in your case, the Elasticsearch host was serving HTTP requests, but Kibana was configured to use an HTTPS URL.

To fix this, update your YAML configuration file by changing the `elasticsearchHosts` value to use the correct protocol and hostname, as shown below:

```yaml
elasticsearchHosts: https://elasticsearch-master:9200
```

By specifying the `https` protocol in the `elasticsearchHosts` configuration, you ensure that Kibana communicates with Elasticsearch using a secure HTTPS connection. After making this change, Kibana should be able to retrieve the version information from the Elasticsearch nodes without encountering the SSL error.

Remember to restart Kibana after modifying the configuration file to apply the changes.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow.  It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since both of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.